# Why a JSP Form doesn't send UTF-8 to a Controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

Here is my source code:

Web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And here is my JSP form

```
<f:form action="insertProduct.htm" method="POST" commandName="newProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productName">Tên tour:</label>
    <f:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tên Tour" path="productName">
    </f:input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price">Giá:</label>
    <f:input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Giá Tour" path="price">
    </f:input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="discount">Giảm giá (0-100):</label>
    <f:input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Giảm giá (%)" path="discount">
    </f:input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Tiêu đề:</label>
    <f:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tiêu đề" path="title" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="departureLocation">Điểm xuất phát: </label>       
    <f:select path="departureLocation">
      <c:forEach var="c" items="${listCatalog}">
        <f:option value="${c.catalogName}" label="${c.catalogName}">
        </f:option>
      </c:forEach>
      <%--<f:option value="2" label="Inactive"></f:option>--%>
    </f:select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="catalogId">Điểm đến:</label>
    <f:select path="catalogId">
      <c:forEach var="c" items="${listCatalog}">
        <f:option value="${c.catalogId}" label="${c.catalogName}">
        </f:option>
      </c:forEach>
    </f:select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="departureDate">Ngày xuất phát:
    </label>
    <f:input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Ngày xuất phát" path="departureDate" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="numDay">Số Ngày:</label>
      <f:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Số ngày" path="numDay" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="people">Số Người:</label>
      <f:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Số người" path="people" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="status">Trạng thái:</label>
     <f:select path="status">
       <f:option value="1" label="Active">
       </f:option>
       <f:option value="2" label="Inactive">
       </f:option>
     </f:select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="created">Ngày tạo:</label>
      <%
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
      %>
      <f:input type="text" class="form-control" value='<%=df.format(new java.util.Date())%>' path="created" readonly="true" ></f:input>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="productContent">Nội dung:</label>
      <f:textarea type="text" id="content" rows="10" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" path="productContent" />
      <%--<f:input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nội dung" path="productContent" />--%>
  </div>          

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="imageMain">Ảnh chính:</label>
    <f:input type="file" id="images" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" path="imageMain" />
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Thêm mới"/>
  <input type="button" class="btn btn-info" value="Trở lại" onclick="history.go(-1)"/>
</f:form>
```

Here is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String insertProduct(@ModelAttribute("newProduct") Product p, HttpServletRequest request) {
    //Lay đường dan va ten anh
    String path = request.getRealPath("/jsp/images");

    path = path.substring(0, path.indexOf("\\build"));
    //
    path = path + "\\web\\jsp\\images";
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload uploader = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    try {
        // lấy danh sách request
        List<FileItem> lst = uploader.parseRequest(request);
        for (FileItem fileItem : lst) {
            if (fileItem.isFormField() == false) {
                //path
                p.setImageMain(fileItem.getName());
                //upload to folder
                fileItem.write(new File(path + "/" + fileItem.getName()));
            } else {
                // Lấy tên thuộc tính
                String name = fileItem.getFieldName();

                // Lấy giá trị thuộc tính
                String value = fileItem.getString();
                // Kiểm tra và set giá trị các thuộc tính cho đối tượng product
                if (name.equals("productName")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setProductName(value);
                } else if (name.equals("price")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setPrice(Float.parseFloat(value));
                } else if (name.equals("discount")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setDiscount(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("catalogId")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setCatalogId(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("title")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setTitle(value);
                } else if (name.equals("departureLocation")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setDepartureLocation(value);
                } else if (name.equals("status")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setStatus(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("departureDate")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    Date convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(value);
                    p.setDepartureDate(convertDate);
                } else if (name.equals("numDay")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setNumDay(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("people")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setPeople(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("created")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    Date convertDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(value);
                    p.setCreated(convertDate);
                } else if (name.equals("people")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setPeople(Integer.parseInt(value));
                } else if (name.equals("productContent")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setProductContent(value);
                } else if (name.equals("people")) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    p.setPeople(Integer.parseInt(value));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    boolean check = productModel.insertProduct(p);
    if (check) {
        return "redirect:getAllProduct.htm";
    } else {
        return "admin_addProduct";
    }
}
```

When i click submit button, i tried print all values pass from my jsp Page but it's not true, Example i input Hà Nội, the value in Controller is HÃ  Ná»?i

On jsp Page i imported

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

I found that when i use RequestMethod.POST, all values is true.
But it's a Insert Product so i cant use RequestMethod.GET.

Please help me!!!!
Sorry about my English

Comment: Hello, try to set your request encoding at the start of your method to UTF-8 : `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`

Comment: i set it in my Controller but it doesn't work :(

Comment: it might be just your java Console not set to UTF-8, what is the value is the value in your dataBase ?

Comment: i set nvarchar for all text input in DB

Comment: try this out : System.out.println(new String(value.getBytes("UTF-8")));

Comment: It changes "HÃ  Ná»?i" to "HÃƒÂ  NÃ¡Â»Â™i"